# If no picture comes from CRM, then blank white

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

We'd like to use SSRS reports via fetch XML in CRM 2011 for generating our quotes.

So instead of having the pictures for all the products in the report, 
I'm converting the picture coming from the product form in a picture on the quote.
(That's the entity "annotation", where I use the picture attached to the productform via note.)

I use the following string in the Field on the report, which should have the pictures in it:

> =System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!ac_documentbody.Value))

The problem is, none of the "manual products" which you can create "on the fly" in Opportunity(Product) have a picture because they don't have an annotation or note.
"Manual product" may not be the correct term to use but I hope it's understandable.

My goal is that I want to edit the String on my picturefield on the report so that when manual products are on it, there will be a blank white picture showing instead of the little red "X".

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to in-write products.

You can add an `IIF` condition to check `Fields!ac_documentbody.Value`, if contains a value you convert it and display it, otherwise you display tour blank white picture.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried that with 
`=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ac_documentbody.Value), " " , System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!ac_documentbody.Value))` but I don't how to make a blank pic and where in my situation, because I don't have any pictures enbetted in my report. Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: so embed a picture inside your rdl

Comment: ok. I tried that, but my "Select the image source" property is "external" in the wanted field. Can I access the embedded pictures there too? Could you provide the syntax for that?